# Run js code via console on each refresh

Tags: javascript, firefox

I want to run simple javascript code on page through firefox console. 
Something like that:

```
  var yesno=1;  
  setInterval(function(){
    $("input[name='elementname']").click()
  }2500)
```

That would works if page wouldn't reload on each click. So I am wondering if there is any method (not necessary using firefox browswer) to run this code automatically on each reload.

Comment: afaik this is only possible through a plugin: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Developing_add-ons

Comment: you can use the dotjs extension for Chrome. Something simulare is Greasemonkey for FireFox